# What does it mean to use setDelegate: on a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, objective-c

I recently saw some code in a UIApplicationDelegate class that looks like the following:

```
[rootViewController setDelegate:self];
```

What exactly does it mean to set the delegate for a UIViewController here? What type of events will the delegate property trigger off on?

Answer (score -3):

There is no setDelegate method on UIViewController, so it wouldn't mean anything, and would only trigger a "does not respond to selector" exception.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was down voted, as UIViewController does not have a delegate property. If you try the above code now, it will not compile. That all assumes of course that in the original code that Coocoo4Cocoa was referencing, the rootViewController object is based on UIViewController.